# Recovery Time for Logistic model equation with harvesting

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, perturbation-theory, biology, mathematical-biology

We are given a logistic growth model with constant harvesting as:

$\frac{dN}{dt} = rN(1-\frac{N}{K})-Y_0$

We are asked to show that the recovery time for harvesting a yield $Y_0$, $T_R(Y_0)$, satisfies

$\frac{T_R(Y_0)}{T_R(0)} = \frac{1}{(1-\frac{Y_0}{Y_M})^{1/2}}$

We define recovery time as the time taken for a pertubation to decrease by a factor of e.

I am aware of the fact that:
$T_R(Y_0) = \frac{1}{r}$

However, apart from this I am mostly lost. How would one approach this problem? Would we find the stable points and use linearization from that point, by finding dn/dt? Or would we directly solve the integral and find the recovery time?

Comment: What do you mean by perturbation here?

Comment: @KBS I mean pertubation as in change of population

Comment: That's still not clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you have
$$
T_R(0)=\frac{1}{r}\,, 
$$
not $T_R(Y_0)$.

To do the computations, you also need first to show that the maximal yield in this model is given by
$$
Y_m=\frac{rK}{4}\,.
$$

After this is just arithmetic. First, for $Y_0>0$ you have two equilibria, but only the larger one (stable) is of interest. This equilibrium has the coordinate
$$
\hat N=\frac{-r+\sqrt{r^2-\frac{4rY_0}{K}}}{\frac{-2r}{K}}\,.
$$
Since you need to linearize about this point, plug $N=u+\hat N$ in your equation and keep only the linear terms in $u$, you should find
$$
\dot u=\left(r-\frac{2r \hat N}{K}\right)u+\ldots,
$$
now
$$
T_R(Y_0)=\frac{1}{r-\frac{2r \hat N}{K}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{r^2-\frac{4rY_0}{K}}}.
$$
Now you can calculate that
$$
\frac{T_R(Y_0)}{T_R(0)}
$$
is exactly what is being asked in your problem.